# Why does Redis Server not allow me to connect to a node?

Tags: redis, fedora

On src directory, I am running below command

```
/redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005
```

but getting below error.

```
Creating cluster
[ERR] Sorry, can't connect to node 127.0.0.1:7000
```

However if I start the node at 7000 using command `redis-server redis.conf` where redis.conf is below

```
port 7000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 10
cluster-slave-validity-factor 0
appendonly yes
```

and similarly I started `redis` in all ports successfully.

Now when I run

```
/redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005
```

I am getting another erorr.

```
Creating cluster [ERR] Node 127.0.0.1:7000 is not empty. Either the node already knows other nodes (check with CLUSTER NODES) or contains some key in database 0.
```

please help.

Answer (score 20):

The first error is because `redis-trib create` attempts to connect to the redis instances while creating the cluster- however you do not have any redis instances running at 127.0.0.1:7000.

The second error looks like you started your redis instance, but now your cluster cannot be created because you already tried to create a cluster on node 7000 (Probably allocated slots to your node) before you got the first error message. To wipe the node clean, run

```
$redis-cli -p 7000
127.0.0.1:7000> flushall
127.0.0.1:7000> cluster reset
127.0.0.1:7000> exit
```

then your redis-trib create will work.

Answer (score 1):

Perform steps in the following manner
stop -> clean -> start -> create
of the servers.